# How can I set the x-axis to a timeline in a plotly icicle?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, icicles, icicle-diagram

I want to create an icicle, but where the x-axis represents a timeline.

Example of a plotly icicle:
[image]

I want to maintain the hierarchical structure, but introduce a timeline on the x-axis. For example:
[image]

Can I vary the length of each rectangle in a plotly icicle to represent time?

Answer (score 0):

That's a totally different type of graph, namely a Gantt chart:
https://plotly.com/python/gantt/

I think under water it this is creating a horizontal bar chart, but that doesn't matter for the purpose.

Comment: But I want a mixture of these two: I want a hierarchical gantt chart.